# Correspondence between curl command and node's request

Tags: node.js, curl, http-post, node-request

How can I execute this cURL shell command `curl --data "{\"obj\" : \"1234556\"}" --digest "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@www.someurl.com/rest-api/v0/objectpost"` that correctly returns expected values using node's request package? 
I tried with those post options but got no success:

```
var request = require('request');
var body = {"obj" : "1234556"};
var post_options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    auth: {
        'user': 'USERNAME',
        'pass': 'PASSWORD',
        'sendImmediately': false
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json',
        'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(body).length,
        'Accept': "text/json",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        'Pragma': "no-cache"
    },
    timeout: 4500000,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}
request(post_options, callback);
```

This way the body is not parsed (got something like `missing required parameter: "obj"`), and I can't understand if it's a matter of encoding or just passing it in the wrong place (i.e. should not be the body). Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems like your cURL usage may be incorrect? You're sending a JSON-like string, but cURL by default will send `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which does not match the payload.

Comment: Edited the answer that was not clear enough: basically the cURL command works fine, is the one I received as an example, but the node request don't

Comment: Did you try `application/json` instead? Otherwise you can try a urlencoded form submission instead, like: `var post_options = { url: url, method: 'POST', auth: /* ... */, timeout: 4500000, form: body };`

Comment: Thanks @mscdex, most likely this is the solution: `var post_options = { /* ... */, timeout: 4500000, form: body };` , so far now it works fine. Could you please post a link or explain this suggestion better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, cURL will send a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless you use `-F` (which changes it to `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`) for your fields or explicitly override the header (e.g. `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`). However, the data being sent by your cURL example seems to be JSON. So the server will get confused and won't correctly find the data it's expecting.

So the solution is one of two options:

1. Try `application/json` as a `Content-Type` in your code instead of `text/json`.
2. Actually use urlencoded formatted data instead of JSON by using the `form` property. `request` will take that `form` object and do all the conversions and setting of headers, etc. for you. For example:

   ```
   var post_options = {
     url: url,
     method: 'POST',
     auth: {
       user: 'USERNAME',
       pass: 'PASSWORD',
       sendImmediately: false
     },
     timeout: 4500000,
     form: body
   };
   ```